# Python Append dictionary in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
[{'Size': 0.0}, {'Size': 19.391637}]
[{'ContainerID': '9bcb46615a',
  'MemUsage': 2.85546875,
  'MaxMem': 1.9522056579589844},
 {'ContainerID': '9aadddf8e0',
  'MemUsage': 17.203125,
  'MaxMem': 1.9522056579589844}]
```

I have the two lists with dicts above, how can I append the first to the second such that:

```
[{'ContainerID': '9bcb46615a',
  'MemUsage': 2.85546875,
  'MaxMem': 1.9522056579589844,
  'Size': 0.0},
 {'ContainerID': '9aadddf8e0',
  'MemUsage': 17.203125,
  'MaxMem': 1.9522056579589844,
  'Size': 19.391637}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Python3:

```
s1 = [{'Size': 0.0}, {'Size': 19.391637}]
s2 = [{'ContainerID': '9bcb46615a', 'MemUsage': 2.85546875, 'MaxMem': 1.9522056579589844}, {'ContainerID': '9aadddf8e0', 'MemUsage': 17.203125, 'MaxMem': 1.9522056579589844}]

final_dict = [{**a, **b} for a, b in zip(s2, s1)]
```

Output:

```
[{'MemUsage': 2.85546875, 'ContainerID': '9bcb46615a', 'MaxMem': 1.9522056579589844, 'Size': 0.0}, {'MemUsage': 17.203125, 'ContainerID': '9aadddf8e0', 'MaxMem': 1.9522056579589844, 'Size': 19.391637}]
```

Explanation: the `**` is called dictionary unpacking. It splits the contents of the dictionary into its respective key-value pairs and allows you to merge them into one dictionary.

If you are using Python2:

```
final_data = [dict(a.items()+b.items()) for a, b in zip(s2, s1)]
```

Output:

```
[{'Size': 0.0, 'MemUsage': 2.85546875, 'ContainerID': '9bcb46615a', 'MaxMem': 1.9522056579589844}, {'Size': 19.391637, 'MemUsage': 17.203125, 'ContainerID': '9aadddf8e0', 'MaxMem': 1.9522056579589844}]
```

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered, so there is no relevance to which is the first key.

Comment: @Ajax1234 You sir rock!! Thank you so much. If you don't mind can you please explain what this means [{**a, **b} for a, b in zip(s2, s1)]

Edit: Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Doing it in-place (`l1`, `l2` are your lists):

```
for d1, d2 in zip(l1, l2):
    d2.update(d1)
```